# JavaScript and childNodes

Tags: javascript, datagrid

I recently inherited a asp.net jquery site to make changes. I started to code in all the changes and moved up from jquery 1.10 from 1.4.

I moved from VS 2008 to VS 2010

I injected bootstrap 3.0 to make the site more pretty, etc.

I removed the meta tag at the start of the master page that ensured the page would run in IE 7 and switched it over to  so that it would be more current with today's technology.

We are using IE 9

So far everything went smoothly until I hit a minor snag.

It involves iterating through an asp.net control called Datagrid. Instead of using server code (C#) to iterate through the childNodes, the previous coder used inline javascript.

The inline java script had worked previously until I made the changes. I ran into the following oddities that had me scratching my head.

for example:

```
var oDataGrid = document.getElementById(grdTA);
for(j = 0; j < oDataGrid.childNodes.length; j++) 
{
  var tBody = oDataGrid.childNodes(j); 
    ....(and so on)
```

I was getting an expected a function error with the line:

```
var tBody = oDataGrid.childNodes(j);
```

so I had to switch to:

```
var tBody = oDataGrid.childNodes[j];
```

notice the brackets.

However, I ran into more problems such as trying to assign a value to:

```
childNodes[0].value = "1";
```

Has something changed in regards to how javascript conducts this type of iteration code in regards to datagrid control (not gridview control)

Is there a documentation that I should review?

thanks,

Comment: you can set childNode.data or childNode.textContent, but i think value is a read-only getter. at any rate, you don't really want to mess with TEXT nodes anyway, use innerHTML if you only care about IE9+...

Comment: So basically I would use childNodes[0].innerHTML("1"); - it still comes back as null..thanks.

Comment: no, innerHTML only works for elements, not node. try textContent, text, and data properties on lowly nodes; it's been so long since i've needed mess with that headache i can't even recall which property actually "sticks". it's far preferable to edit a grid using higher-level abstractions than with nodes. in particular, .children is like .childNodes but only for elements and tables provide .rows and .cells collections. examples: oDataGrid.children[2].children[3].innerHTML="hello"; oDataGrid.rows[5].cells[3].innerHTML="hello";

Comment: Thanks..for some reason any of the properties after childNodes[0]..is gone, null or undefined..such as childNodes[0].value etc...